# How to make variables appear as inches or pounds

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a couple variables appear as pounds and inches when it prints.

```
while True:
name = input("\nEnter players name or, 0 to quit: ")
if name == "0":
    break

height = float(input("Enter players height in inches: "))

weight = float(input("Enter players weight in pounds: "))

bmi = weight * 703 / height * height

print("\nBMI Profile Of %s" % name,"Height: ",height,"Weight: ",weight,"BMI Index: ",bmi,sep = "\n")
```

So my question is how would I make the variable height appear as inches or " and weight as lbs.

Comment: That BMI calculation doesn't look right. Check [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and add parentheses as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str` to convert those integers to strings the add addition strings using +:

```
print("\nBMI Profile Of %s" % name,"Height: ",str(height)+" inches","Weight: ",str(weight) + " lbs","BMI Index: ",bmi,sep = "\n")
```

Output:

```
BMI Profile Of Scott
Height: 
60 inches
Weight: 
200 lbs
BMI Index: 
140600.0
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Do you have any idea why the BMI index is so high though? Im using the formula I got and the math is right but on our example its only 2 digits. Like the example I got was 70" and 135 lbs with a 19.4 BMI index. But if I use those inputs its 94905.00

Comment: Your units are incorrect for [BMI](https://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/how-can-i-work-out-my-bmi.aspx?CategoryID=51).  Weight in kilograms and height in meters.

Comment: Im not sure im understanding. I want the units to be inches and pounds. and the formula im using is the one I was told I need to use.

Comment: Im still confused but I got it to work using this website: http://extoxnet.orst.edu/faqs/dietcancer/web2/twohowto.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use as per below. and concact using `str`. `"` for height and `lbs` for weight.

```
while True:
  name = input("\nEnter players name or, 0 to quit: ")
  if name == "0":
      break

  height = float(input("Enter players height in inches: "))

  weight = float(input("Enter players weight in pounds: "))

  bmi = weight * 703 / height * height

  print("\nBMI Profile Of %s" % name,"Height: ",str(height) +  '″', "Weight: ",str(weight) + " lbs","BMI Index: ",bmi,sep = "\n")
```

**Output**

```
BMI Profile Of Test
Height: 
186.0″
Weight: 
75.0 lbs
BMI Index: 
52724.99
```